# update if exists else insert with two unique columns mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is the columns I have

```
id           - primary key
product_id   - unique key
customer_id  - unique key
```

And here is my query

```
INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_rating(product_id, customer_id, rate_value) values(123,25,2) on duplicate key update rate_value = 2
```

First time it is inserted correctly in second time when I rate from same customer and with different product id like this

```
INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_rating(product_id, customer_id, rate_value) values(1213,25,3) on duplicate key update rate_value = 3
```

Column rate_value is updated from 2 to 3 instead of inserting new row.

It is taking unique value for customer_id alone I guess. Right?

Comment: yes. Because you set unique key for `customer_id`

Comment: But I set unique key for both product and customer id. Why it is taking customer_id alone?

Comment: you specify alone for particular field. So you set like this `UNIQUE KEY id_box_elements (product_id,customer_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
create table t(id int,product_id  int,customer_id  int,
               rate_value int,
UNIQUE KEY id_box_elements (product_id,customer_id ));
```